# Mixing questions between Qualtrics Blocks

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, qualtrics

I am creating a questionnaire on Qualtrics and I have 3 different blocks of questions. Let's call them `A, B, and C`. Each of the blocks has 100 questions each. I want to **randomly** pick 15 questions from each of the blocks. That part is easy. I have used Randomization options available for each block.

However, I want to mix questions across these blocks. Currently, what I can get is

`A1 A2 ... A15   B1, B2, ... B15   C1, C2, ... C15`

**All the questions from one block appear together.**

I want to randomize this specific ordering as well. My requirements are:

1. 15 questions from each block selected randomly from a pool of 100 in each block.
2. Randomly displaying this pool of 45 questions to the user.

How can I do this? I've been stuck at this for hours now. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any easy way to do this.

You could put all 300 questions in the same block.  Then in a block before the 300 question block have 3 multiple choice questions (QA, QB, QC) where you have placeholders for the 100 questions as choices (QA: A1, A2, ..., A100; QB: B1, B2, ... , B100; QC: C1, C2, ..., C100).  For each of those questions used Advanced Randomization to randomly display 15 choices. Hide the questions with JavaScript. Then in your 300 question block add display logic to each question based on whether its corresponding choice was displayed in the applicable QA, QB, QC question.